# MYSQL Injection and md5 encryption

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, md5, code-injection

If I encrypt a MYSQL injection with md5, will it still execute? If I encrypt the MYSQL injection before I do the "mysql_real_escape_string" will it be able to null the mysql injection? Should I run the "mysql_real_escape_string" before I encrypt?

Comment: What do you mean by encrypting an injection? Do you have an example?

Comment: Should probably mention that you're looking at a PHP solution explicitly, as a tag or in the question body itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`md5()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) returns a string containing the ASCII characters 0-9 and a-f. An SQL injection requires using characters like `'` or `"`, thus a hashed string that was generated by md5() won't cause an SQL injection EVER, considering that the algorithm works expectedly.

Thus you can write something like this without worry:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['username'] );
$password = md5( $_POST['password'] );
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$username' AND pass='$password'");
```

But it's a good practice to always escape the data that you pass to your query with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: See I usually do this using "sprintf()" then mysql_real_escape_string as the second parameter to the query. Didn't know if I could escape a md5 encrption, but it seems i dont need to worry about it if they cant use it maliciously when it's encoded

Comment: A 'good practice' is to escape all untusted teztual data. MD5 return can be trusted. Escaping all data without discrimination leads to two issues: 1. escaping is not always the way to sanitize data (think numbers) 2. not a common thing, but you can actually run into 'double escaping' issue.

Comment: @Mchl: **All** the data is untrusted because it is handled by the most untrusted entity - the programmer. That's why it IS a good practice to escape all the data that you pass to your SQL query.

Comment: Great. I would certainly not trust a programmer who thinks like that. How will escaping help here then? `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = $ID";` How will escaping help with data that's been already escaped?

Comment: Of course you won't. As I wrote - the programmer is the only one to make the mistake. That's why it's good to use a method to build your SQL queries, which might use vprintf(), as a general-purpose solution. Instituting a coding convention would help in reducing the problems you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hashed a value with MD5, it no longer contains any maliciously injectable characters.  MySQL will not decode the MD5 hash and interpret/execute it as SQL.  In fact, the MD5 hash cannot be decoded, as it is a one-way algorithm.

Comment: Or so it was designed, but it's not nearly as strong as intended.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 hashed values are binary data which are represented hexadecimal in php. This means, they only contain the numbers 0..9 and the letters A..F.
SQL injections are not possible with this letters, so you are safe.

Answer (score 1):

MD5 hashed values themselves can't cause an SQL injection, but if you're trying to avoid an SQL injection your approach is a very good way to *cause* one.

You special case one class of variables that can't cause an injection (MD5'd passwords), then you special case another (e.g. things evaluated to integers), then you forget which should be escaped and which not, you end up with one little tiny insignificant variable that should be escaped but isn't and nobody from your team spots it.... Oops, there's a real vulnerability in your code.

You avoid escaping one safe class, you avoid escaping a second safe class, and then you you incorrectly assume that a third class is also safe – it turns out, the MD5 was in a binary encoding and somebody managed to find a way to create an injection with it... Oops... You have one more real vulnerability in your code.

You should:

1) Always use parametrized queries. This makes escaping unnecessary and avoids the risk of forgetting to escape something. Use `mysqli` and [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('insert into users (username, password) values (?, ?)'); 
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $name, md5($password));
$stmt->execute();
```

2) If for some reason you can't, escape everything. Even if it is unnecessary. You don't want to forget something.

Rule to fight against SQL injections is: Don't try to learn what is safe and what isn't, assume everything is unsafe, and treat everything as unsafe. If you treat a safe value as unsafe, the program will still function correctly, if you treat an unsafe value as safe your program will contain a huge security hole, and one mistake is enough.

Answer (score 0):

While in general md5 hashed values cannot be used in injection attacks, it's worth pointing out that **raw** md5 hashes values can be exploited. Raw md5 hashes are hashes generated with
`md5($userSubmittedValue, true)` -- they're vulnerable because the output is a string that can contain non-hexadecimal output.. While it's not common to generate hashes in raw form, it's important to note that technically hashed values can be exploited in injection attacks.

Here's an example of how it can be done:

http://cvk.posterous.com/sql-injection-with-raw-md5-hashes

As other have pointed out, though, hexadecimal md5 output is not vulnerable to injection attacks.